# Sum of all integers up to $x$ with digit sum $t$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation

If $S(x,t)$ is the sum of all integers up to $x$ whose sum of digits is $t$, is there a way to calculate it? I mean for high arbitrary $x$.

For example, $S(120,11) = 29+38+47+56+65+74+83+92+119 = 603$

I was trying to work with the integers mod $9$ (because an integer mod $9$ is equal to its sum of digits mod $9$) but haven't seen any pattern emerge. I assume it is somehow related to the count of such integers.

It would be best to find an exact formula or a way to calculate it exactly, but an asymptotic approximation for its limit as $x$ is large would be nice to see as well.

Comment: Probably not easily. A little easer when $x$ is one less than a power of $10,$ maybe.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I thought of that. But I am interested in arbitrary $x$.

Comment: The sum of digits of $101$ is $2$, not $11$.

Comment: Yeah, you won't probably be able to get a good closed formula for arbitrary $x.$ For $x=10^k-1,$ you'll get $$\frac{10^k-1}{9}\cdot \frac{t}{k}\cdot M$$ where $M$ is the coefficient of $x^t$ in the expansion of $$\left(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\right)^k.$$

Comment: In general, $$M=M_{t,k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^k\binom{k}i\binom{t+k-1-10i}{k-1}$$ or something close to that. So even that formula is a bit messy.

Comment: So for $x=99=10^2-1$ and $t=11,$ $M_{11,2}=\binom{12}{1}-\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}=8,$ and you get a sum of $11\cdot\frac{11}2\cdot 8=484,$ which is $119$ less than your sum up to $120.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually this is very nice derivation, thank you!